# Случайные числа с++

Tags: c++, математика, случайные-числа

Как правильно сгенерировать случайные числа от -20 до 70

```
= (double)(rand() % 90 + (int)(-20));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Только и того, что у вас получаться будут *только целые числа* от -20 до 69 включительно. Если уж хочется через `rand()` получать действительно равномерно распределенные числа с плавающей точкой - то это

```
= rand()*90.0/RAND_MAX - 20.0;
```